# Deleting multiple rows selectively from Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 19,000 datapoints in each row, now my problem is how to delete 20 rows simultaneously after an interval of 10 rows?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Please add some sample data showing the kind of transformation you want to make.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify: You want to keep the first ten rows of data, delete the next twenty rows, and then repeat the pattern? If so, insert a new column to the left of your data, mark the rows to be deleted using the following formula, filter out the blanks (rows to be kept), and then delete all rows marked with an "x".

I'm assuming that you have headers in row 1, and your data starts in row 2. Paste this in A2 and fill it down. If your data starts somewhere other than A2, just edit *ROW(A$1)* to reference the cell directly above wherever you paste this formula.

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW(A$1),31)>10,"x","")
```

This formula counts the number of rows it is from the reference, divides by 31, and then returns the remainder. If that remainder is larger than 10, then it's a row that you want to delete.

I used 31 because *MOD(30,30)* returns zero. Just to illustrate how MOD() works a little further, you could also use this formula to accomplish the same thing.

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW(A$1)-1,30)>=10,"x","")
```

There are two adjustments there. One of them shifts the zero from row 30 to row 1, and the other is to keep the "x" from shifting also.

[image: See it in action]

Comment: You don't have to thank anyone in advance, but rather accept the best answer after the fact.